# How can I set this registry value from my installer

Tags: c#, .net, windows, wix, installation

In my *.msi* installer package, I have a C# custom action that writes a registry value in:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

The custom action is deferred because I need elevated privileges for some of the keys I am trying to install. However, because it is deferred, this action writes to the current user of the system account since it is launched with elevated permissions, so my registry value actually gets written in:

```
HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run
```

How can I get the installer to write this registry value into the registry of the user who launched the installation package instead of the system account's registry?

Comment: You can do this with WiX without writing any code at all. Use HKCU and it just works. What's wrong with that?

Comment: @PhilDW Because I have an x86 installer package, and I don't plan on making an x64 installer package. My x86 package sometimes needs to add registry entries into the x64 hive, which the installer won't do by default, and if you were to try, you'll be banging your head into the wall for hours until you realize that you then need to make another installer package for x64 machines...but I chose to conditionally install registry entries through custom actions, since my install files are all x86, and I have only one installer for both architectures this way, as opposed to two installers.

Comment: ok, you didn't mention that. You're fighting an uphill battle because you need two MSI files. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/heaths/archive/2008/01/15/different-packages-are-required-for-different-processor-architectures.aspx and yes it's a pain. However, what you need is this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx and the .NET equivalent, which appears to be to use RegistryView.Registry64. That may work in your code.

Comment: @PhilDW Thanks for the links. I got it working and finished the installer, tested it and its working very well on multiple operating systems and architecture combinations. It wasn't very bad and makes for a single MSI, except I had to bundle .NET Framework 4 in my bootstrapper to make use of RegistryView.Registry64, which wasn't a big deal at all. I created my own registry traversal extensions that came in extremely handy. The hardest part was installing registry keys, but good logging came in handy. WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User helped me set user keys based off SID in HKEY_USERS.

Answer (score 1):

```
Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey key;
key = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");
key.SetValue("Name", "Isabella");
key.Close();
```

Do you try this, here reference from [microsoft](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx)

**Edit:**

```
string strSID = "";
string userName = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name;
NTAccount ntuser = new NTAccount(userName);
SecurityIdentifier sID = (SecurityIdentifier)ntuser.Translate(typeof(SecurityIdentifier));
strSID = sID.ToString();

Registry.Users.SetValue(sID + @"\key", value);
```

Try this, you should probably read about `Registry.Users.SetValue`

You need:

```
using System.Security.Principal;
```

for this code.

Comment: Yes, above is the code that does not work for me. I use both **RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64).CreateSubKey("Names");** and **Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey("Names");** depending on the operating system architecture.

Comment: The problem is that **CurrentUser** is not always the same. For example, when a Windows installer package is run, the user account changes when the installer goes into an elevated mode. This is because the installer is running under the system account, not the user account who initially launched the installer.

Comment: Thanks, actually it does help, but I went with something slightly different. I'm using WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().User to get the SID of the user who launched the installer (since it doesn't require admin privileges to obtain), then I just drill into that HKEY_USERS key from my installer using that SID.