# Visual Studio Setup Project custom actions are not finding the correct registry keys in Current User

Tags: c#, visual-studio, registry, vdproj

Our software requires that the user has either Excel 2010 or 2013 installed before we can finalize our installation. We are using the Visual Studio Setup Project (vdproj) with custom actions to check HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office for either 14.0\Excel or 15.0\Excel to ensure it is there. The code looks something like this:

```
RegistryKey currentUser = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Office");
if (currentUser != null)
{
    foreach (key in currentUser.GetSubKeyNames())
    {
        if (key == "14.0")
        {
            // Excel 2010 is installed
        }
        else if (key == "15.0")
        {
            // Excel 2013 is installed
        }
    }
}
```

The current implementation has not been changed for a little over a year now and we haven't had any issues before. However, recently we have seen that some machines are not returning all of the sub key names. Most machines that this is affecting is returning only the "Outlook" key and nothing else, despite the fact that there is the "15.0" key as well as many others that exist in that location.

This is not an issue with x86 vs x64 since HKCU\Software\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Office does not exist on those machines. Regardless, I did already try `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, RegistryView.Registry64)`, but that did not seem to help.

Answer (score 1):

The issue actually stems from a recent Windows Update ([See relevant KB article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3072630) for explanation and possible workaround).

When specifying `Registry.CurrentUser` with elevated privileges, it doesn't actually use the HKEY_CURRENT_USER registry hive, but rather HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT. The sub key names returned from `currentUser.GetSubKeyNames()` are actually the keys found in HKEY_USERS\.DEFAULT\Software\Microsoft\Office. We were able to work around this by forgetting `Registry.CurrentUser` entirely and are using `RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64)` instead.

If someone absolutely needs to use HKEY_CURRENT_USER, I haven't tried it myself but [this answer + comments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26242260) might be relevant.